# how to do maths using ints that have been coverted into strings (python)

Tags: python

I'm making a text based world domination game using python, And for the currency in the game I want to put it in a print statement, so I converted the currency from int to str, and know if I try to subtract from it, it gives me a error.

So I tried, to convert the int into str by for example: money = str(1000) and then do: money -=100
then print("you have" + money + "left"), but I got a error when running it.

Comment: If it is helpful to know, I'm using Google Collab to run my code.

Comment: So just _don't_ convert to a string I guess?!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "And for the currency in the game I want to put it in a print statement, so I converted the currency from int to str, and know if I try to subtract from it, it gives me a error." Then **don't do that**. Do the math first, and **then** use **completely different technique** to deal with the fact that you "want to put it in a print statement". Please see the linked duplicates. Numbers are for math. Strings are not for math.

Comment: You can convert to string on demand: `print(str(money))`. `money` itself never needs to be a `str`.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can do int(money) to do math again.
But, why did you convert money into a string lol.
You just should keep it in int, and to print the value see :  https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/formatted-string-literals-f-strings-python/

```py
money = 1000
money = str(money)

int_money = int(money)
int_money -= 1000

print(f"You have {int_money} left)
```